# Why does this code produce 3 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

Why does the following code produce `a == 3`?

```
var x = "abc";
var y = 3;
var z = "xyz";
var a = x && y || z;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingmedia/qBZAL/

I would have expected this to result in `a == true`.

Why is the logical operator evaluating `"abc"` as `true` but doesn't evaluate `3` as `true`. Instead it produces `3` as the result.

Furthermore, if you change `y = 0` then `a == "xyz"` which means that `&&` treated `0` as `false`. What happen to treating a number as a number?

What's going on here with the logical operators?

Comment: anyone have a better title for this question?

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @gnat seemed like a general programming question.

Comment: "Why" questions are difficult to answer. Why does the code produce that result?  **Because that is what the ECMAScript specification states it should return**, and the implementation is a correct implementation of the specification. Is that answer satisfying or unsatisfying?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is to be expected.

In JavaScript (and many other languages), not only Booleans themselves are true or false, but other objects can be truthy or falsey as well (See [the docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)):

> The value […] is converted to a boolean value, if necessary. If value is […] is `0`, `-0`, `null`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`, or the empty string (`""`), [it is] false. All other values, including any object or the string `"false"`, create […] true.

The logical operators `||` and `&&` don't return `true` or `false`, rather they return the last argument to influence whether they are truthy or falsey ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)):

> - `expr1 && expr2` – Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `&&` returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
> - `expr1 || expr2` – Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, `||` returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

Answer (score 10):

1. The first step is to evaluate `"abc" && 3`.

   - `false && 3` would return `false`,
   - `true && 3` would return `3`.

   "abc" is not false, so JavaScript takes the second part, i.e. 3.

The second step is to evaluate `3 || "xyz"`. Here, JavaScript takes the first value which is not null, i.e. 3. This is similar to `this.firstObject ?? this.defaultValue` in C#: the second part is taken only when the first part is null.

Comment: Just to add a small bit, the _gotcha_ here is that the logical AND and OR operators do not return a boolean value, they return the value of the last operand that they actually evaluate. `false || null` will equal `null` for example.

Answer (score 1):

the side effect is that you can do things like this:

```
x = x || {};
```

to set a variable to a default if it is not set.

Or

```
TrackingManager && TrackingManager.track("user was here")
```

to avoid bulkier if statements.